# VueJs, difference between computed property and watch property?

Tags: vue.js, properties, watch

I just started learning vuejs, but I didn't quite understand what **Computed** and **Watch-Property** were. what? What is the benefit? where to use?

Comment: The Vue docs describe this in [*Computed vs Watched Property*](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property).

Comment: No. Watcher is different from watch properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me try to explain it in a simple way.

**Computed Property:-**

If you are coming from C# or Java background **computed property** is the property with a getter and setter e.g. In C# or Java we declare

```
public int Month
{
    get
    {
        return month;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((value > 0) && (value < 13))
        {
            month = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now Let it map to Vue js It will be like

```
computed: {
    month: {
        // getter
        get: function () {
          return this.month
        },
        // setter
        set: function (value) {
          if ((value > 0) && (value < 13))
            {
                month = value;
            }
        }
      }
}
```

Be default computed properties have getter only. We can define setter also like in the above example. Setter will invoke when the values update in the element where you bind this computer property e.g. `<input v-model="month"/>`

In simple if you want a property with the 2-way binding you can use computer property.

**Watch Property:-**

When we want to update data on the base of the other data. We'll use Watch Property. **Remember It is not recommended to overuse watch property.** Now come to the example

```
watch : {
    kilometers:function(val) {
        this.kilometers = val;
        this.meters = val * 1000;
    },
    meters : function (val) {
        this.kilometers = val/ 1000;
        this.meters = val;
    }
}
```

Now let we have 2 text boxes & our these 2 watch properties are bind with the text boxes e.g.

```
<input type = "text" v-model = "kilometers">
<input type = "text" v-model = "meters">
```

Now if we change the or enter the value in any text box in the other text box value is automatically updated based on the logic inside the watch property.